# socket io group emit is not working when running on nodejs cluster

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I made a chat application in which I am emitting to the group using

```
 var io = require('socket.io')(/*passing https server here*/);
 var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
 io.adapter(redis({/*redis server host port*/}));
 function emitToGroup(groupId) {
     io.sockets.in(groupId).emit("channel", data);
 }
```

I am running in an Ubuntu server(14.04) machine with node.js(6.10.x) clustered environment. Emitting to group is working fine when clustered mode is off, but it's not working when clustered mode is switched on. One more peculiar thing is that clustered mode is working when running on windows machine.

Comment: Hi Pranay, can you describe in detail what you mean by "not working"? What is the behavior you're expecting? What is actually happening? How are you testing the behavior of emit?

Comment: https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/

Comment: @ArchitBaweja emit is not reaching the connected socket io clients

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk i had referred the same link and implemented the same